# why does my progress bar do not update itself

Tags: reactjs, web, components, progress-bar, heroicons

```
const Home = ({ isHovered }) => {
    // State and context declarations
    const [isHover, setIsHover] = useState(false);
    const [isPaused, setIsPaused] = useState(true);
    const [secLeft, setSecLeft] = useState(0);
    const [mode, setMode] = useState('Focus');

    const isPausedRef = useRef(isPaused);
    const secLeftRef = useRef(secLeft);
    const modeRef = useRef(mode);

    const mainInfo = useContext(MainContext);
    const settingInfo = useContext(AdjustmentContext);

    // Initialize timer
    function initTimer() {
        setSecLeft(settingInfo.workMinutes * 60);
    }

    // Switch between work and break modes
    function switchMode() {
        const nextMode = modeRef.current === 'work' ? 'break' : 'work';
        const nextSec = (nextMode === 'work' ? settingInfo.workMinutes : settingInfo.breakMinutes) * 60;

        modeRef.current = nextMode;
        setMode(nextMode);

        secLeftRef.current = nextSec;
        setSecLeft(nextSec);
    }

    // Timer tick
    function tick() {
        setSecLeft(secLeftRef.current - 1);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        initTimer();

        const interval = setInterval(() => {
            if (isPausedRef.current) {
                return;
            }
            if (secLeftRef.current === 0) {
                return switchMode();
            }
            tick();
        }, 1000);

        return () => clearInterval(interval);
    }, [settingInfo]);

    // Calculate progress
    const totalSec = mode === 'Focus' ? (settingInfo.workMinutes * 60) : (settingInfo.breakMinutes * 60);
    const percent = Math.round((secLeft / totalSec) * 100);
    const min = Math.floor(secLeft / 60);
    let sec = secLeft % 60;
    if (sec < 10) sec = '0' + sec;

    return (
        <div className='grid grid-flow-row'>
            <div className='flex flex-col justify-center items-center'>
                <div>
                    {/* Progress bar */}
                    {mode === 'Focus' ? (
                        <div className={`${isHovered ? 'opacity-50' : ''}`}>
                            <CircularProgressbarWithChildren
                                value={percent}
                                text={`${min}:${sec}`}
                                styles={buildStyles({
                                    textColor: '#000',
                                    pathColor: '#ffffffff'
                                })}
                            >
                                <img style={{ width: 150, marginTop: -5 }} src={focus} alt="focus" />
                            </CircularProgressbarWithChildren>
                        </div>
                    ) : (
                        <div className={`${isHovered ? 'opacity-50' : ''}`}>
                            <CircularProgressbarWithChildren
                                value={percent}
                                text={`${min}:${sec}`}
                                styles={buildStyles({
                                    textColor: '#000',
                                    pathColor: '#ffffff'
                                })}
                            >
                                <img style={{ width: 150, marginTop: -5 }} src={freeTime} alt="It's Break Time" />
                            </CircularProgressbarWithChildren>
                        </div>
                    )}
                </div>

                {/* Buttons */}
                <div className='flex mt-5'>
                    {isPaused ? <PlayButtons /> : <PauseButtons />}
                </div>

                {/* Mode selection buttons */}
                `rest code`
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Home;
```

The progress bar in my application is exhibiting two critical issues. Firstly, it seems to remain dormant until the timer approaches the one-minute mark, and then it halts after roughly two minutes. This problematic behavior likely stems from the way the timer interval is managed. It's crucial to guarantee that the timer consistently decrements, irrespective of the remaining time.

Secondly, there's a noticeable problem when switching between modes, such as transitioning from 'Focus' to 'Break' or vice versa. The progress bar fails to adjust accordingly to these mode changes. This issue may be linked to how the state and references associated with the timer and mode are handled.

To address these pressing issues, a careful review of the code is necessary. Start by ensuring that the timer initializes correctly and commences from the appropriate initial value. Double-check the interval timing to ensure that the timer updates continuously, regardless of the remaining time. When switching modes, both the mode state and the corresponding timer value should be updated accurately.

Additionally, utilizing debugging techniques such as console.log statements or debugging tools can be immensely helpful in tracking variable values and identifying the root cause of the problems. Lastly, confirm that all dependencies, including 'react-circular-progressbar,' are correctly installed and up-to-date.

[[before 1 min left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LWPgT.png)]
[after 1 min left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxQJW.png)]